# Silverlight windows phone 8.1 project: Unable to navigate to page 2

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I have a weird issue. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am doing a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app project that (for now) has two pages. Page1.xaml has a Welcome page with a button, that, when clicked takes you to a second page with two textblocks one LongListSelector and one textbox,that accepts only numbers (*InputScope="Number"*). The LongListSelector is for selecting countries and it has it's own logic of the alphakeygroups and everything else (JumpList, GroupHeader, ItemTemplate). For the click event of the button in page1, this is what I've put in

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

This is supposed to take me to the page two but it doesn't. Here're the errors I get:[image: Error 1]
after I click Continue twice (the Emulator button changes to Continue), I get this:
[image: Error 2]

I tried with a dummy page, Page3_test.xaml, and that works fine. When I click the button on page1, it takes me to page3.

What am I doing wrong?

VS2013 - U4; W8.1;

Comment: and you upload the whole project somewhere? (like a zip on onedrive / dropbox)

Comment: Do you have Page2.xaml in your project? Is it perhaps inside some folder?

Comment: @IgorKulman No. This project only stays in my hard drive. This is a test project. If things I want to do works on this, I replicate that on my master project, which is also not backed up.

Comment: @igrali It is in the same project as the others. That was the frst this i verified. I switched to silverlight because I wanted to make use of the long list editor. I have a similar one going on a Universal project, and that is going just fine. I've finish that almost 70%. SL,for some reason doesn't want to play alone.

Comment: And this is what I did. i removed Page2 from my project and copied pasted all the relevant code from it to Page3. I changed the Navigation path to Page3 and I GET THE SAME ERROR! I really suspect it is the LongListSelector that's causing this, but I can be wrong. Please help!

Comment: Nope, I removed LongListSelector and all code behind it. Same issue. BTW, when I add a new item (as a new page, right click Soln Explr and Add New Item), I select Windows phone portrait page. Then i remove all the pre-loaded items in it, like the StackPanels and the TextBlocks and everything else, strip it to bare minimum and then add my own tools. Do you think that is causing this? Because when I tested with Page3_test.xaml, it was not stripped at all. I just kept it as is, and began working on it. When I copied and pasted all the code form Page2 to it, i removed everything from it..

Comment: @AnonymousPerson I am not asking about any backups.. I am simply suggesting you upload the project somewhere so people can download it and take a look at the problem

Comment: No, never done that. You mean a TFS or GIT, is it?

Comment: I've recreated the project and it seems to be working fine. Thank you for looking into this. Now there seems to be a little screw up with the LongListSelector. I will try to figure that out. Thnx :)